# Convert String to Date with phones with differents date formats

Tags: ios, swift

I have some troubles parsing string date to Date format.

I recibe from one API the date string with this format `2020-08-27 12:39:32` (the date come in 24 hour format) and I have an extension of String to convert it to Date. So I do the convertion like this:

```
apiTime.toDate(format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

All works fine if the phone is configured with 24 hour. The problem came when the app runs in a AM/PM date format because the date return nil.

This is my extension to convert String to Date.

```
extension String {
    func toDate(format: String) -> Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self) //here return nil with AM/PM format
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but this will create a new date formatter every time you call this method. HH is for 24 hour time format am pm symbols don't make any sense here.

Comment: @LeoDabus what do you recommend to do in this case? Send the DateFormatter to the function? And I use the AM PM symbols because in others parts of the code I convert from 12 hours format using the same function.

Comment: It's not clear what happens here. Do you receive a different string depending on which phone you are on? In that case, _that_ is the problem you need to solve.

Comment: @gnasher729 looks like the issue here might be that OP it is not setting the date formatters locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting the date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @LeoDabus it's better not to create `DateFormatter` every time (this is very resource-consuming). You can extract it, eg. as a static property.

Here is a simple demo:

```
class Test {
    static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        return dateFormatter
    }()
    
    func parseDateExample() {
        let apiTime = "2020-08-27 12:39:32"
        if let date = apiTime.toDate(formatter: Self.dateFormatter, format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") {
            print(date)
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

You can reuse the formatter in your String extension instead of creating a new one every time you call `toDate`:

```
extension String {
    func toDate(formatter: DateFormatter, format: String) -> Date? {
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.date(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and I saw that I forgot the line of the locate. `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`